# How do I turn off specific listchars in my current file?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

In my .vimrc file I have listchars set to showing tabs and trailing spaces.

```
set listchars=trail:~,tab:>-
```

How do I change my settings for the file I currently have open to stop showing the tabs?

Comment: > stop showing one or two, 
"one or two" what?

Comment: I thought the context of my question would make that clear but I suppose not. My bad. I meant one or two of the characters from the _listchars_ group

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you please be more specific? For instance, list your current `'listchars'` setting and tell us which one you would like to stop showing? Or an example of a file with `:set list` enabled and the specific display you would like to disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim, `listchars` is a global setting, so it is not possible to configure it per-window.

It is possible however to turn on and off `list`, using `setlocal list` and `setlocal nolist`.

In neovim, `listchars` is a global or local-to-window setting.  So to configure it per window you merely need to use

```
setlocal listchars=eol:c
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with [Vim 8.2.2518](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2518), ['listchars'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27) is a global or local-to-window setting. So you can use 'setlocal' to set a window-local 'listchars' setting.